# Scilab - For loop with changing index

Tags: for-loop, scilab

I am having trouble with a very simple for loop in Scilab.

```
max_inventory = 0;

for j=1:120

    S(j) = max_inventory + 1;

    if (S(j)<90) then
        cost(j) = 27;

        elseif (90<=S(j)<=110) then
        cost(j) = 25;

        else
        cost(j) = 22;
    end


    max_inventory = max_inventory + 1;


end
```

Basically, I want S to have an index j. So, with 120 iterations, there will 120 different values of S. Namely, S_1, S_2,..., S_120.

With the if-else condition, I want the "cost" to have a different value depending on what S(j) is.

But, I keep getting the error:

> Undefined operation for the given operands. check or define function
>   %b_3_s for overloading.

I am not sure what this error really mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in

```
if (90<=S(j)<=110)
```

You cannot code this test like this. Write it like

```
if (90<=S(j) && S(j)<=110)
```

Comment: You are a savior. Thank you!